# Distinct select on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What i am trying to do is a simple recommender , must take the biggest weighted top 40 element's node2 element. Calculation for weight comes from `(E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE)`. Now this code succesfully returns top 40 elements. However, **i don't want `E.NODE2` to return duplicates**. POSTGRE SQL allowed me to do `SELECT DISTINCT ON  (NODE2) E.NODE2 ,  (E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE)`. How can i do the same in oracle?

The complete sql query;

```
SELECT *
 FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT E.NODE2  , (E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE)
    FROM KUAISFAST K, EDGES E
    WHERE K.ID = 1 AND K.COURSE_ID = E.NODE1 AND E.NODE2 NOT IN(
        SELECT K2.COURSE_ID
        FROM KUAISFAST K2
        WHERE K2.ID = 1
        ) 
    ORDER BY( E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE ) DESC) TEMP
WHERE rownum <= 40
```

Comment: Regarding **i don't want E.NODE2 to return duplicates**, that's somehow related to not arbitrarily choosing any qualified row; you shouldn't choose one only(unless your program just show data samples based on criteria and not exactly on the statistics-side of things), duplicates are inevitable. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611822/distinct-with-count-and-sql-server-2005  In short, approach Postgreql's `DISTINCT ON` with caution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem, altough quite slow

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM   (SELECT E.NODE2 ,  max(E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE ) AS MAXDE
    FROM KUAISFAST K, EDGES E
    WHERE K.ID = 1 AND K.COURSE_ID = E.NODE1 AND E.NODE2 NOT IN(
        SELECT K2.COURSE_ID
        FROM KUAISFAST K2
        WHERE K2.ID = 1
        ) 
        GROUP BY E.NODE2 )
ORDER BY MAXDE DESC)
WHERE rownum <= 40
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT 
      E.NODE2,
     (E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE),
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.NODE2 ORDER BY E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE DESC) R
  FROM 
      KUAISFAST K,
      EDGES E
  WHERE 
      K.ID = 1 AND 
      K.COURSE_ID = E.NODE1 AND 
      E.NODE2 NOT IN
        (  SELECT K2.COURSE_ID
           FROM KUAISFAST K2
          WHERE K2.ID = 1
        ) 
    ORDER BY (E.WEIGHT * K.GRADE) DESC
) TEMP
WHERE R=1 AND 
ROWNUM <= 40
```

Answer (score 1):

In your subselect, I think you want:   `MAX(E.WEIGTH * K.GRADE)` so that only one value comes back for each `E.NODE2`.

This means you'll need to `GROUP BY E.NODE2` as well.