# PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, sql-limit

I'm looking for something similar this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP n WITH TIES FROM tablename
```

I know about `LIMIT` in PostgreSQL, but does the equivalent of the above exist? I'm just curious as it would save an extra query each time for me.

If I have a table `Numbers` with attribute `nums`: `{10, 9, 8, 8, 2}`. I want to do something like:

```
SELECT nums FROM Numbers ORDER BY nums DESC LIMIT *with ties* 3
```

It should return `{10, 9, 8, 8}` because it takes the top 3 plus the extra `8` since it ties the other one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Postgres 13** finally adds [`WITH TIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) . See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)

---

There is [no `WITH TIES` clause up to PostgreSQL 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT), like there is in [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).
In PostgreSQL I would substitute this for `TOP n WITH TIES .. ORDER BY <something>`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY <something>) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rnk <= n;
```

To be clear, [`rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) is right, [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) would be wrong (return too many rows).
Consider this quote from the SQL Server docs (from the link above):

> For example, if expression is set to 5 but 2 additional rows match the
> values of the ORDER BY columns in row 5, the result set will contain 7 rows.

The job of `WITH TIES` is to include all peers of the last row in the top *n* as defined by the `ORDER BY` clause. `rank()` gives the exact same result.

To make sure, I tested with SQL Server, here is a [live demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63525/top-n-with-ties).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=3a7963fb052e5a486144035df8d27a87)*

Faster alternatives for big tables in Postgres 12 or older:

- [Equivalent for FETCH FIRST WITH TIES in Postgres 11 with comparable performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074473/equivalent-for-fetch-first-with-ties-in-postgresql-11-with-comparable-performanc/71074731#71074731)

Comment: Why this complicated? The rank() function will do exactly what is required?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are absolutely right (as was I, at first) My second considerations were uncalled for.

Comment: @Erwin: that's nice(http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63525/top-n-with-ties), I didn't know stackoverflow has a built-in module to run queries :-) Though the output of 10,10,9 for 10,9,8,8,2,10 is incorrect if you need to get the top 3(10,9,8) and list all those 10,9,8; which should be: 10,10,9,8,8. `WITH TIES` might be incorrect for some given problem case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611822/distinct-with-count-and-sql-server-2005/2612456#2612456

Comment: @MichaelBuen: I am sure there are situations out there where you want the results from `dense_rank()`. But the question here refers to `top n with ties`, which is an obvious reference to SQL server syntax. Consequently, `rank()` is the right one here.

Comment: Anyway, we will know from the OP, it depends on his problem's case

Comment: If the top two tie, then there will only be one more so 10,10,9 is right.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL already supports **`OFFEST FETCH`** clause and starting from version 13 it will support **`FETCH FIRST WITH TIES`**:

> [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html)
>
> ```
> [ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ count ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES } ]
> ```
>
> **The WITH TIES option is used to return any additional rows that tie for the last place in the result set according to the ORDER BY clause**; ORDER BY is mandatory in this case.

Query:

```
SELECT nums 
FROM Numbers 
ORDER BY nums DESC
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=487428f48e04bc693179f0aa2a1b25ba)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Output: 10, 9, 8, 8

```
with numbers (nums) as (
  values (10), (9), (8), (8), (2)
) 
SELECT nums FROM Numbers 
WHERE nums in (SELECT DISTINCT nums FROM Numbers ORDER BY nums DESC LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY nums DESC
```

Output: 10,10,9,8,8

```
with numbers (nums) as (
  values (10), (9), (8), (8), (2), (10)
) 
SELECT nums FROM Numbers 
WHERE nums in (SELECT DISTINCT nums FROM Numbers ORDER BY nums DESC LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY nums DESC
```