# Find top 3 users per location

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, top-n

I am fairly new to SQL, working on some practice problems. I have a sample Twitter database and I am trying to find the top 3 users in each location based on number of followers.

Here are the tables I am using:

```
id_follower_location

        id       | followers | location 
-----------------+-----------+----------
 id28929238      |         1 | Toronto
 id289292338     |         1 | California
 id2892923838    |         2 | Rome
 .
 .

locations

           location       
----------------------
 Bay Area, California
 London
 Nashville, TN
.
.
```

I've been able to find the "top" user by:

```
create view top1id as 
  select location, 
    (select id_followers_location.id from id_followers_location 
      where id_followers_location.location = locations.location 
      order by followers desc limit 1
    ) as id 
  from locations;

create view top1 as 
  select location, id, 
    (select followers from id_followers_location 
      where id_followers_location.id = top1id.id
    ) as followers 
  from top1id;
```

The only way I have been able to come up with so solve this is by finding out the "Top 1st", the "Top 2nd", the "Top 3rd" and then using `union` to combine it. Is that the correct/only way of doing this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can a user have more than one location?

Comment: @FoolishSeth yes to postgres and no to user have more than one location. Thank you

Comment: Like with most questions of this kind, you forgot to mention how to deal with **ties**? What do you want to return when 5 people share the same number of followers? Do you want *exactly* three rows per location? How to decide? Random? Arbitrary? Additional criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Top n

With `rank()` you get **at least 3** rows (fewer if fewer exist). If there are ties among the top 3 *ranks*, more rows may be returned. See:

- [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562#9630562)

If you want **exactly 3** rows per location (fewer if fewer exist), you have to break ties. One way is to use [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) instead of `rank()`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, location
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY followers DESC) AS rn
   FROM   id_follower_location
   ) r
WHERE  rn <= 3
ORDER  BY location, rn;
```

You may want to add `ORDER BY` to the outer query to guarantee sorted output.
If there are more than three valid candidates, you get an arbitrary pick from ties - unless you add more `ORDER BY` items in the `OVER` clause to break ties.

#### Top 1

As for your query to get the *top 1* row: there is a *much* simpler and faster way in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (location)
       id, location           -- add additional columns freely
FROM   id_follower_location
ORDER  BY location, followers DESC;
```

Details for this query technique in this closely related answer:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with windowing functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

For example (not tested may need slight syntax fixes):

```
SELECT follower_ranks.id, follower_ranks.location 
FROM (
    SELECT id, location, 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY followers DESC) 
    FROM id_follower_location
) follower_ranks 
WHERE follower_ranks.rank <= 3;
```