# Select N latest rows per school, but skip duplicates from the same student

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

In a Postgres db (engine version 14.6), I have two tables: `school_students` and `id_cards`. They look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE school_students (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    school_id character varying NOT NULL,
    student_id character varying NOT NULL
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX school_students_pkey ON school_students(id int8_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX school_students_school_student_idx ON school_students(school_id text_ops,student_id text_ops);

CREATE TABLE id_cards (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    school_student_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES school_students(id)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_cards_pkey ON id_cards(id int8_ops);
CREATE INDEX id_cards_school_student_id_idx ON id_cards(school_student_id int8_ops);
```

ID cards are periodically reissued to students, so there may be any number of cards per student. Each card is unique. Each student+school entity is unique. A student may belong to multiple schools.

There are currently 11 schools in the system with number of students in each ranging anywhere from ~200 to ~20000. Most students have one id card, but they may issued new cards at any time and there is no limit to how many id cards they may have.

Here is an [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/USjqxuTu) with sample data.

In front of the DB is an API with a resource whose job it is to take a list of `school_ids` and retrieve the list of the most recently created id cards for each school+student, limited to a select number of students per `school_id`. The API is to be queried frequently enough that it must be performant.

I have the following query to get me what I need without any limiting:

```sql
SELECT id FROM id_cards
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(c.id) FROM id_cards c
  JOIN school_students ss ON c.school_student_id = ss.id
  WHERE
    school_id in (1, 2, 3) -- up to 100 ids per application code. in practice, there are only a dozen or so schools
  GROUP BY
    school_id,
    student_id
);
```

However, in my sub-query, I'd like to limit the number of school+student records returned to 100 for each `school_id` listed in the where clause in order to avoid runaway queries in instances where a given school may have a large number of students. For instance, the latest id card issued for up to the 50 of most recently added students for school 1, the id card for up to 50 of the most recently added students for school 2, repeat for each school listed in the query.

Is there a performant query that will accomplish this?

Comment: Note: IDs are poor surrogates for time ordering. Add a created_at datetime column.

Comment: Yup will end up doing that in the not too distant future.

Comment: Use `distinct on`

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase the title to address the core of the question. Similar for tags.

Comment: To get the optimal query, you also need to disclose Postgres version, cardinalities (roughly how many rows in each table, how many distinct schools, students, cards) and the range of possible and typical limits for the query. Are new schools added dynamically or is the list of schools stable for some time? If so, at least a materialized view of schools would be useful. Is performance even relevant? Please update the question with relevant details.

Comment: Also, the view is just noise. An optimized query is based on the underlying tables. Sample values for the **tables** would be more useful. Ideally, add a fiddle like I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter fair enough. I added this info to the description and included a fiddle. I left in the view only because my example query makes us of it.

Comment: The core problem is the number of rows per school. Your example limit is *2*. The best query for a limit of 2 is not the best for a limit of 1000. So tell us the *actual* limit (or range of limits) you need to implement. How important is performance? Any decent query is still pretty fast for just a couple 100k rows. And is there a different limit per school? Always results for all schools, or given schools, or an arbitrarily limited number of schools?

Comment: 1) Your ids are in text, which is odd. 2) They're not declared as foreign keys, which is a referencial integrity problem. 3) school_students.student_id is not indexed (the composite index can be used backwards, but it's slow). 4) The view seems unnecessary, it's just hiding a simple join. 5) school_students probably doesn't need a separate primary key, (school_id, student_id) should do.

Comment: @Schwern 1) agreed, but that's inherited and not easily changeable 2) they aren't foreign keys to anything in this db. There is another service that owns these ids. 3) good point. 4) fair enough 5) the separate primary key allows id_cards to have a FK to point to it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I used the limit example of 2 only for a concise return in the question, but your point is taken. I removed that example as well as reference to the view. I also stated the actual limit I'm looking for, as well as the max number of schools enforced in application code (mostly inconsequential since there are only a dozen).

Comment: @askingquestions 1) Composite foreign keys are allowed, but I agree an integer is simpler.  2) You probably should have schools and students tables anyway to protect referencial integrity, then you can have simple integer foreign keys (less to store, less to index).

Comment: Aside: There are multicolumn FK constraints. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25430588/939860 (But the single column has some pros, too.)

Comment: ErwinBrandstetter, schwern many thanks for all of the input here. This gives me a lot to chew on. Will look into creating schools/students tables and a materialized view. In the meantime, the answers are useful and get me moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutilated relational model makes more efficient query techniques impossible.

The mentioned view is irrelevant for performance optimization. A view is basically just a stored query. It has no data nor indices of its own. A view is a convenience feature that doesn't help performance. (Not to be confused with a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html).)

The main table `id_cards` only features `school_student_id`. There is no way to immediately deduce a school from this number. So there is also no way to add an index to speed up the query at hand. Indexes apply to **one** table in Postgres (and most other RDBMS). My initially suggested smart queries are useless without a matching index.

That said, for the moderately few rows in your DB, even a "brute force" query with a (single!) sequential scan on both tables (the only remaining option unless you add a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` or change the relational model) is not that expensive. This should be as good as it gets:

```sql
SELECT card_id
FROM  (
   SELECT card_id
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY school_id ORDER BY card_id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.school_id, s.student_id)
             s.school_id, c.id AS card_id
      FROM   id_cards c
      JOIN   school_students s ON s.id = c.school_student_id
      ORDER  BY s.school_id, s.student_id, c.id DESC
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
WHERE  rn <= 2; -- your limit
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cfDgMKTd)

Related:

- [Find top 3 users per location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995271/find-top-3-users-per-location/15999855#15999855)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

About the (optional) optimization with `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`:

- [Find first 3 orders for each customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533266/find-first-3-orders-for-each-customer/72824267#72824267)

**If** we **know** that all result rows are among the N most recent entries, we could work with that, and optimize above query:

```
SELECT card_id
FROM  (
   SELECT card_id
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY school_id ORDER BY card_id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.school_id, s.student_id)
             s.*, c.id AS card_id
      FROM  (
         SELECT *
         FROM   id_cards
         ORDER  BY id DESC
         LIMIT  1000         -- this covers the latest 2 for all schools (!)
         ) c
      JOIN   school_students s ON s.id = c.school_student_id
      ORDER  BY s.school_id, s.student_id, c.id DESC
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
WHERE  rn <= 2;
```

Note that the (highly unrealistic!) data distribution in your fiddle adds all the latest rows for a single school, so this optimization would not apply!

Also, the increased limit of 100 (up from 2) in your updated question makes this optimization a lot less juicy (or even applicable).

Reading only the top N rows from an index (and sorting) is proportionally faster than reading a couple 100k rows. In this case (but not for the general query above), it would help to make the PK into a covering index and get index-only scans out of it like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE id_cards
  DROP CONSTRAINT id_cards_pkey
, ADD  CONSTRAINT id_cards_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) INCLUDE (school_student_id);
```

See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207938/3684)

Then again, selecting the "latest" entries based on a serial ID is unreliable to begin with. Concurrent write load and other internals can mess with the sequence. Such IDs are only guaranteed to be unique, not necessarily sequential. An added timestamp is more reasonable. (Plus rules how to break ties.)

BTW, **Postgres 16** (and to some extent already pg 15) has multiple improvements over Postgres 14 that help the performance of these queries. Compare:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U5CTWTRv)

Among other things, `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` doesn't help any more, because [the optimization is built-in now](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAApHDvohAKEtTXxq7Pc-ic2dKT8oZfbRKeEJP64M0B6%2BS88z%2BA%40mail.gmail.com). (Doesn't hurt, either.)

#### Outdated answer for initial question

(While still assuming a *table* `school_id_cards`.)

If your table is big you want to avoid expensive whole-table sequential scans. Use a smart query to pick qualifying rows with index(-only) scans from a matching index. Hugely faster.

Typically, there should exist some kind of "school" table in your DB with exactly one row per relevant school. Makes the query simpler and faster:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE latest_card AS (
   SELECT c.*
   FROM   school s
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT c.school_id, c.card_id, ARRAY[c.student_id] AS leading_ids
      FROM   school_id_cards c
      WHERE  c.school_id = s.school_id
      ORDER  BY c.card_id DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) c

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.*
   FROM   latest_card l
   JOIN   LATERAL (
      SELECT l.school_id, c.card_id, l.leading_ids || student_id
      FROM   school_id_cards c
      WHERE  c.school_id = l.school_id
      AND    c.card_id < l.card_id
      AND    c.student_id <> ALL (l.leading_ids)
      ORDER  BY c.card_id DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) C ON cardinality(l.leading_ids) < 2  -- your limit per school here!
   )
SELECT card_id
FROM   latest_card
ORDER  BY card_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-xLVaAHh)

This scales well for a small limit per school like you demonstrated. For a large limit, I would switch to a different query.

About the use of a recursive CTE (rCTE):

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Be sure to have a matching index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON school_id_cards (school_id DESC, card_id DESC);
```

A simpler index with (default) ascending sort order is barely any worse. Postgres can scan B-tree indices backwards. Only opposing sort order would be less ideal.

**If** there is no `school` table:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE latest_card AS (
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (school_id)
          school_id, card_id, ARRAY[student_id] AS leading_ids
   FROM   school_id_cards c
   ORDER  BY school_id DESC, card_id DESC
   )

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.*
   FROM   latest_card l
   JOIN   LATERAL (
      SELECT l.school_id, c.card_id, l.leading_ids || student_id
      FROM   school_id_cards c
      WHERE  c.school_id = l.school_id
      AND    c.card_id < l.card_id
      AND    c.student_id <> ALL (l.leading_ids)
      ORDER  BY c.card_id DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) C ON cardinality(l.leading_ids) < 2  -- your limit per school here!
   )
SELECT card_id
FROM   latest_card
ORDER  BY card_id;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

You could replace the non-recursive term with another, nested rCTE to generate the list of schools (possibly with the latest card to kick things off) ...
But there really should be a `school` table. Create it if you don't have it.

Comment: Regarding your comment about a `schools` table: there is a `school_students` table and an `id_cards` table. For our purposes school+student is a unique identity, and this database doesn't contain any additional info about school or student (e.g. name, dob), so there isn't a need for `schools` or `students` tables; that info is kept in a separate db behind its own service. The `school_id_cards` view mentioned in the post joins `school_students` and `id_cards`. Will update the post with this info and with index info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this example, the return value is correct (supposing I also add the `where school_id in` filter), but the query still fetches all of the school+student records before later omitting them from the return set. I didn't mention this in my original post (I have since edited it), but the primary purpose of the limit is to avoid having to scan all school+student entities for every school in the list. Can we avoid this kind of scan?

Comment: @askingquestions: *"schools table: ... that info is kept in a separate db behind its own service."* That's actively unhelpful for the task at hand. If you have access to that other db, you might reference the schools table as [`FOREIGN TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to avoid rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by building up a query of subqueries and [`dense_rank`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-dense_rank-function/).

First, get the latest cards for each student/school. (*Note: IDs are poor surrogates for time ordering. Add a datetime column.*)

```
select 
  *,
  dense_rank() over(partition by school_id, student_id order by card_id desc) as student_card_order
from school_id_cards
```

Next, we use that as a subquery to get the order of the most recent cards issued to students by school. The most recent cards have `student_card_order = 1`.

```
with ordered_student_cards as (
  select 
    *,
    dense_rank() over(partition by school_id, student_id order by card_id desc) as student_card_order
  from school_id_cards
)
select
  *,
  dense_rank() over(partition by school_id order by card_id desc) as school_card_order
from ordered_student_cards
where student_card_order = 1
```

And, finally, we can fetch only the first two per school. `school_card_order <= 2;`

```
with ordered_student_cards as (
  select 
    *,
    dense_rank() over(partition by school_id, student_id order by card_id desc) as student_card_order
  from school_id_cards
), ordered_school_cards as (
  select
    *,
    dense_rank() over(partition by school_id order by card_id desc) as school_card_order
  from ordered_student_cards
  where student_card_order = 1
)
select card_id
from ordered_school_cards
where school_card_order <= 2;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/j_ancEbs).

There may be a more compact or performant way to do it, but window functions and subqueries are a way to break down complex queries.

Comment: Thanks for this. These will be not infrequent queries run as part of an API, so I want to avoid table scans (will update my post with this), which it looks like happens here.

Comment: Did you try with realistic amounts of data? With so little data, sequence scans are faster than index scans, so Postgres will choose them. Also, pay attention to how many rows are being scanned.

Comment: If the data doesn't get updated frequently, and I can't imagine it is, materialized views might be the simplest optimisation. Either the subqueries, or the whole query, or all.