# Top 10% of sum() Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, top-n

I'm looking to pull the top 10% of a summed value on a Postgres sever.

So i'm summing a value with sum(transaction.value) and i'd like the top 10% of the value

Comment: Please show us some sample data and the expected output

Comment: I have customers with customer id's and a value they have spent so i'd like the top 10% of the customers who have spent money.

Select
customer.id,
sum(transaction.value)
from
customer




Basically the output would be:

Customer_Id   Total Value
3218947932     289.00

Comment: When you say 10% you mean the customers that sums up 10% of total sum (e.g. if total is $100 you have the firsts that sums up to $10) or 10% of number of rows (e.g. if you have 100 rows, you want the 10 first rows as result)?

Comment: The latter of the two. If there are 100 rows each with their own sum value, i'd like the top 10% of those number of rows.

Comment: Essential information should go into the question, not just into comments. Please *edit* your question for better response. (Press "edit" left under the question.)

Answer (score 4):

From what I gather in your comments, I assume you want to:

1. Sum transactions per customer to get a total per customer.
2. List the top 10 % of customers who actually *have* transactions and spent the most.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t.customer_id, sum(t.value) AS sum_value
   FROM   transaction t
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum_value DESC) AS sails_rank
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY sum_value DESC
LIMIT (SELECT count(*)/10 FROM cte)
```

#### Major points

- Best to use a CTE here, makes the count cheaper.
- The `JOIN` between `customer` and `transaction` automatically excludes customers without transaction. I am assuming relational integrity here (fk constraint on `customer_id`).
- Dividing `bigint / int` effectively truncates the result (round down to the nearest integer). You may be interested in this related question:
  [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562)
- I added a `sails_rank` column which you didn't ask for, but seems to fit your requirement.
- As you can see, I didn't even include the table `customer` in the query. Assuming you have a foreign key constraint on `customer_id`, that would be redundant (and slower). If you want additional columns from customer in the result, join `customer` to the *result* of above query:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t.customer_id, sum(t.value) AS sum_value
   FROM   transaction t
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, sub.sum_value, sub.sails_rank
FROM  (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum_value DESC) AS sails_rank
   FROM   cte
   ORDER  BY sum_value DESC
   LIMIT (SELECT count(*)/10 FROM cte)
   ) sub
JOIN  customer c USING (customer_id);
```