# Making Queries for relaional model

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some troubles with making queries for this task. anyone please help me.

- Cars(License, Brand, Year);
- Employees(EID, Firstname, Lastname,    Wage);
- Customers(CID, Firstname, Lastname, Phone);
- OfficeStaff(EID,    OfficeNumber);
- Own(CID, License);
- Mechanic(EID, HourlyPrice);
- Repairs(License, EID, PartCost, Hours);

Create SQL statements performing the following tasks:

(a) Create the OfficeStaff-table while taking into account that the OfficeNumber may not be NULL and must be in
the range [1..10].

(b) Find the name(s), i.e. firstname(s) and lastname(s), of the owner(s) of the car(s), which have been repaired for
the most times.

(c) Find the average number of hours spent (i.e. Repairs.Hours) repairing cars of brand “Opel”.

(d) Update the HourlyPrice to be 20 EUR for all mechanics with a wage of 100 EUR or more.

**My tries:**
(a) Create the OfficeStaff-table while taking into account that the OfficeNumber may not be NULL and must be in the range [1..10].

```
CREATE TABLE OfficeStaff (
 EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Firstname TEXT,
 Lastname TEXT,
 Wage REAL,
 OfficeNumber INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_OfficeNumber CHECK (OfficeNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
```

b) no idea?!

(c) Find the average number of hours spent (i.e. Repairs.Hours) repairing cars of brand “Opel”.

```
SELECT AVG(R.Hours)
FROM Repairs R, Cars C
WHERE R.License = C.License AND C.Brand = “Opel”
```

(d) Update the HourlyPrice to be 20 EUR for all mechanics with a wage of 100 EUR or more.

```
UPDATE Mechanic
SET HourlyPrice = 20
WHERE Wage >= 100
```

Comment: (a) Create the OfficeStaff-table while taking into account that the OfficeNumber may not be NULL and must be in the range [1..10].
CREATE TABLE OfficeStaff (
 EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Firstname TEXT,
 Lastname TEXT,
 Wage REAL,
 OfficeNumber INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_OfficeNumber CHECK (OfficeNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10)    Is this valid for a)???

Comment: (c) Find the average number of hours spent (i.e. Repairs.Hours) repairing cars of brand “Opel”.

SELECT AVG(R.Hours)
FROM Repairs R, Cars C
WHERE R.License = C.License AND C.Brand = “Opel”

Comment: Please can you post this code to  the original post, it can be edited)

Comment: (d) Update the HourlyPrice to be 20 EUR for all mechanics with a wage of 100 EUR or more.
UPDATE Mechanic
SET HourlyPrice = 20
WHERE Wage >= 100

Comment: It has been added to the original post now.

Comment: Try using a SELECT with ORDER BY for section (b)

Comment: I already tried that but my postgre gave me errors. How would you think of a query that could get me that result, just so I can see the result in postgre

Comment: My teacher does not care about the syntax. I have mySQL and postgre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** how to create can look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html)

```
CREATE TABLE OfficeStaff (
 EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 Firstname varchar(100),
 Lastname varchar(100),
 Wage decimal(15,2),
 OfficeNumber INT NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT CK_OfficeNumber CHECK (OfficeNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
 )
```

**(b)** Not sure about this one, but you have to use `rank` to get not only 1 value among same values. For this you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties)

```
    WITH cte AS (
   SELECT a.Firstname, a.Lastname, rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(c.Hours)) AS rnk
   from Customers as a
   join Own as b
   on a.CID=b.CID
   join Repairs as c
   on b.License = c.License
   group by a.Firstname, a.Lastname
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rnk <= 1;
```

**(c)** join usage [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html)

```
SELECT AVG(R.Hours)
FROM Repairs R
 join Cars C
 on R.license=C.license
WHERE C.Brand = 'Opel'
```

**(d)** update usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)  and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)

```
UPDATE Mechanic
    SET HourlyPrice = 20
    from Employees
    WHERE Mechanic.EID = Employees.EID
    AND Employees.Wage >= 100
```

Comment: Okay, that works perfektly! Thanks, but what about (b) and (d). Those are the ones that annoys me to the limit here.

Comment: @genger-man Please read all material I have provided for your own knowledge

Comment: I am already doing that by the moment. Thank you alot for your time. Really appreciated!