# "TOP N WITH TIES" for MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

SQL Server has a handy operator called ["TOP N WITH TIES"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties), which returns

> two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited results set

For example, `TOP 3 WITH TIES` from {10, 9, 8, 8, 2} will return {10, 9, 8, 8}.

Is there a single-query equivalent for `TOP N WITH TIES` for MongoDB?

I can't use two queries (with the second searching for the minimum value returned by the first) because I'm running the query in a Meteor publish function, which [doesn't let you return more than one cursor from the same collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish).

Comment: What sort of cursor do you need? Is something like the output of `.fetch` okay? It can still be used through a slightly modified more manual publish method. This does sound possible using the aggregation framework, which does not return a cursor.

Comment: [`fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) as is, loses reactivity.

Comment: How important is it that you be precise? Why not return 2*N and work it out on the client?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Not necessarily. You can use a basic match all observer query to check if new records change the results and report it to the client accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to return the subquery to use it as a criterion. This is essentially the same thing you'd have to do in any other SQL engine.

```
var min = Collection.find({},{limit:10, sort: {rank: -1}}).fetch()[9].rank
return Collection.find({rank: {$gte: min}})
```

Comment: A simple solution that returns only one cursor, but still runs two queries.

Comment: this kinda thing will always be 2 queries, there's no way for any DB to know what documents share a tie without looking at all of them. Just depends whether it's got a syntactic sugary topping (sql server) or not. For example, check out the subquery in postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties