# Consecutive streaks/non-streaks based on Win, Draw & Loss grouped by team

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands, cockroachdb

I am trying to calculate streaks across a result database based on win loss and draw criteria.

Goal: Get longest streak of wins/non-wins grouped by team

I have tried different SQL query suggestions from other threads, but I am either missing out the grouping or the team column and often only takes 2-way option(Win and loss) - I need 3-way option(Win, Los, Draw incl. non-win,non-loss and non-draw)

Looked at this - https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data

But I have no clue how to get the team incl. grouping into the mix

Scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE teamresults (matchid varchar(255), date DATE, time TIME, team varchar(255), teamresult varchar(255))
```

Data sample:

```
INSERT INTO teamresults (matchid,"date","time",team,teamresult) VALUES 
('030420181800acfc','2018-04-03','18:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('080420181600brac','2018-04-08','16:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('150420181400aaac','2018-04-15','14:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('180420181800acfc','2018-04-18','18:00:00','AC Horsens','D')
,('210420181600fcac','2018-04-21','16:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('270420181900acfc','2018-04-27','19:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('040520181900acaa','2018-05-04','19:00:00','AC Horsens','W')
,('110520181900fcac','2018-05-11','19:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('180520182000acbr','2018-05-18','20:00:00','AC Horsens','D')
,('210520181800fcac','2018-05-21','18:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('120520191200veac','2019-05-12','12:00:00','AC Horsens','W')
,('190520191400acve','2019-05-19','14:00:00','AC Horsens','D')
,('140720191400acfc','2019-07-14','14:00:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('210720191200siac','2019-07-21','12:00:00','AC Horsens','W')
,('270720191730acfc','2019-07-27','17:30:00','AC Horsens','L')
,('040820191600brac','2019-08-04','16:00:00','AC Horsens','W')
,('010420181400hoag','2018-04-01','14:00:00','AGF','W')
,('080420181800agsi','2018-04-08','18:00:00','AGF','W')
,('130420181900agfc','2018-04-13','19:00:00','AGF','W')
,('170420181900fcag','2018-04-17','19:00:00','AGF','L')
,('230420181900agho','2018-04-23','19:00:00','AGF','L')
,('300420181900siag','2018-04-30','19:00:00','AGF','W')
,('060520181200agob','2018-05-06','12:00:00','AGF','W')
,('130520181800obag','2018-05-13','18:00:00','AGF','W')
,('190520181600ags�','2018-05-19','16:00:00','AGF','D')
;
```

The below query does work, but does only a take single input statement - So I can only get streak of win, loss or draws - Not non-win, non-loss and non-draws.

```
SELECT
   team,
   MAX(cnt)
FROM
 (

SELECT
      team,
      COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM 
    (

SELECT
        team, 
        date,
        teamresult,
        SUM(CASE WHEN teamresult <> 'W'  THEN 1 else 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY team 
              ORDER BY date 
              ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS dummy
      FROM teamresults

      ) dt
         WHERE teamresult = 'W' 
   GROUP BY team, dummy
 ) dt
GROUP BY team;
```

I also want to be able to find longest non-streaks grouped by team

SQL fiddle is available here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a2ac/1

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
Gordon queries are working, but these queries does not work in postgres/cockroach - So now trying to convert them to supported queries via window functions rank()

```
select team, teamresult, cnt, rank() over (order by cnt desc) from
(SELECT team, teamresult, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team, teamresult ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
WHERE teamresult = 'W'
GROUP BY team, teamresult, (seqnum - seqnum_r)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)) as ranked
```

This does gives me an output like this(Data sample from my DB):

```
FC København    W   9   1
AaB             W   8   2
FC København    W   8   2
FC København    W   8   2
FC København    W   8   2
Brøndby IF      W   7   6
FC Midtjylland  W   7   6
FC København    W   7   6
FC København    W   7   6
FC København    W   7   6
Esbjerg fB      W   6   11
FC Midtjylland  W   6   11
AaB             W   6   11
Brøndby IF      W   6   11
Brøndby IF      W   6   11
```

Expected output:

```
Team           Longest consecutive streak
FC København       9
AaB                8
Brøndby IF         7
FC Midtjylland     7
Esbjerg fB         6
```

Comment: define `calculate streaks` Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thx for feedback - Have edited my post to be more precise on expected outcome, incl. current scheme, data and query.

Comment: Please include the desire output with that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the streaks using:

```
SELECT team, teamresult, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team, teamresult ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
GROUP BY team, teamresult, (seqnum - seqnum_r);
```

You can modify this to get the longest winning streak per team:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES team, teamresult, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team, teamresult ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
WHERE teamresult = 'W'
GROUP BY team, teamresult, (seqnum - seqnum_r)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```

If you just want the longest streak of any type, remove the `WHERE`.  If you want the longest for each type per team, then add `teamresult` to the `PARTITION BY`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a2ac/5) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want non-wins, you need to partition by an expression:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES team,
       (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END) as is_win,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team, (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END) ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
-- WHERE teamresult = 'W'
GROUP BY team, (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END), (seqnum - seqnum_r)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks - But unfortunately is breaks on my DB(cockroach)SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with"
  Detail: source SQL:
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES team, teamresult, COUNT(*) as cnt

Comment: How will a non-win streak query look like? Replaceing = with <> for non-wins, return 3 for Horsens, whereas the max streak in the dataset is actually 6.

Comment: Thx for the non-wins :-) - How do I convert the query to support cockroach/postgres? - They do not support 'with ties' - instead they support Rank() as windows function. Looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties, but can't find the logic for how to change the query.

Comment: @MortenStensgaard . . . You can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` if there are no ties.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gordon, I solved my case with the following queries:

**Longest consecutive streak of Wins(replace W with D for draw, and L for loss) grouped by team**

```
select team, max(cnt) longeststreak from (

SELECT team, teamresult, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team, teamresult ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
WHERE teamresult = 'W'
GROUP BY team, teamresult, (seqnum - seqnum_r)
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)

)
group by team
order by longeststreak DESC
```

**Longest consecutive streak of non-wins(replace W with D for non-draw, and L for non-loss) grouped by team**

```
select team, max(cnt) longestnonstreak from (

SELECT team, 
       (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END) as is_win,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT tr.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team, (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END) ORDER BY "date", "time") as seqnum_r
      FROM teamresults tr
     ) tr
GROUP BY team, (CASE WHEN teamresult = 'W' THEN 'W' END), (seqnum - seqnum_r)
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)

)
group by team
order by longestnonstreak desc
```

Thanks to Gordon for assisting in the solution.